# IBM MQ: reconnect to message broker in case of connection error after startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, messaging

I am trying to publish messages on a IBM MQ Queue. 
Here is a my implementation -

```
@Bean("jmsTemplate")
public JmsTemplate createProducer(@Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory cf) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cf);
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("my-queue-name");
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

and then I am calling it in a scheduler to produce message every second -

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("jmsTemplate") JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "1000")
public void runOnStart() {
    String message = "sample message "+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message);
    LOGGER.info(message);
}
```

All works good. Then I shut off the internet and this piece of code started throwing error - saying queue connection not available. I connected my system back to internet and it started sending the messages again. Cool! It worked as I wanted.

I tried to repeat the same experiment using JMS2.0 with javaContext implementation. Here is my second implementation -

```
@Bean("jmsContext")
public JMSContext createProducer(@Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory cf) {
    return cf.createContext();
}
@Bean("jmsProducer")
public JMSProducer createProducer(@Qualifier("jmsContext") JMSContext jmsContext) {
    return jmsContext.createProducer();
}
```

Again, similar to last approach, I created a scheduler to publish messages like this -

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("jmsContext") JMSContext jmsContext;
@Autowired @Qualifier("jmsProducer") JMSProducer jmsProducer;

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "1000")
public void runOnStart() {
    try {
        Destination destination = this.jmsContext.createQueue("my-queue-name"));
        String message = "sample message "+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.jmsProducer.send(destination, message);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in sending message", e.getLinkedException());
    }
}
```

Here also, I am able to send the messages. Very well till now. My issue comes in the following part.
The scheduler was running, I disconnected my system from internet and the code throws error saying there is no connection. I reconnected my system back, but still my messages were not going to the broker(unlike the previous implementation). Isn't it supposed to connect back and send messages?

What have I missed in my 2nd implementation?

Note that: the Bean `@Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory cf` is same for both implementation and it is like  -

```
public static ConnectionFactory getMQConnectionFactory (
        Map<String, String> queueDetails,
        SSLContext sslContext) throws Exception {
    MQConnectionFactory cf = new MQConnectionFactory();
    cf.setHostName(queueDetails.get("hostname"));
    cf.setPort(Integer.parseInt(queueDetails.get("port")));
    cf.setQueueManager(queueDetails.get("queueManager"));
    cf.setChannel(queueDetails.get("channel"));
    cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, queueDetails.get("username"));
    cf.setSSLCipherSuite(queueDetails.get("sslCipherSuite"));
    cf.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    return cf;
}
```

The exception -

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
```

Comment: The main difference is, i guess, that the `JmsTemplate` in this case re-connects for each and every `convertAndSend` whereas the JMS 2.0 implementation doesn't and simply re-uses a single existing connection. So instead of defining the `JMSContext` and `JMSProducer` as beans, you should re-create them when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the underlying MQ client code to reconnect on failure you will need to enable mq auto reconnect like this:

```
cf.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
cf.setClientReconnectTimeout(1800); // how long in seconds to continue to attempt reconnection before failing
```

Comment: Auto re-connect is attempted once for 1800 secs according to this config in a blocking fashion. After timeout, if it did not gain the connection again, it will not try further and will continue throwing connection errors in the scheduled activity every second. What I need is that auto-reconnect should be tried continuously in every, say 5 secs, till 1 hr or say 50 re-connect attempts before giving up.

JmsTemplate seems to do that, but is @M. Deniam correct in his comment in the question? Does  `JmsTemplate` in this case re-connects for each and every `convertAndSend`?

Comment: @Innovationchef Reconnect does not try only once, it will try every few seconds for up to the timeout specified.   If after the timeout it still has not connected it will fail with a reconnect error.   If you want 60 minutes of retries then bump it to 3600. If there is no network path to your destination it will need to timeout each tcp connect attempt before the next based on OS defaults unless you tune this down as well.

Comment: Review this answer for more details on timing out both the active connection (based on channel HBINT) and connection attempts.

Comment: If the SVRCONN has HBINT of the 300 which is the default then the initial channel timeout could take up to 6 minutes.   After this when it attempts to reconnect if the TCP traffic is black holed (as in your case you "disconnected my system from internet", or the server crashed) the connection attempt will timeout based on OS defaults (180+ seconds on RHEL for example).